# Как сделать ответ на неправильный ответ пользователя в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Вот даны хэндлеры,в которых записаны ключевые слова, на ответ которых среагирует пользователь, как мне записать ошибку("Я тебя не понял, повтори пожалуйста").
Нужно написать отдельный хэндлер для такой проверки? Буду ждать ответа)

```
@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text.lower() in [
    'теорема безу', 'безу','деление многочлена','деление многочленов', 'деление многочленов с остатком'])
def bezu(message: types.Message):
    photo1 = open('png/slide-7.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)

@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text.lower() in [
    'гипербола', 'ветки гиперболы','обратно-пропорциональная зависимость','обратно-пропорциональный график', 'обратно пропорциональная зависимость', 'обратно-пропорциональная'])
def giperbolnaya_func(message: types.Message):
    mess10 = 'Обратно пропорциональной зависимостью называют функцию, заданную формулой: y= k/x.\
     В зависимости от знака числа k график обратно пропорциональной зависимости может иметь два принципиальных варианта:'
    photo1 = open('png/Group 7.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess10)
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
```

Comment: жду ответа,если что-то непонятно в вопросе,напишите,постараюсь обьяснить подробнее)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if(message.text.lower in [
    'теорема безу', 'безу','деление многочлена','деление многочленов', 'деление многочленов с остатком'])
):
        #какие-то действия
    elif(message.text.lower in [
    'гипербола', 'ветки гиперболы','обратно-пропорциональная зависимость','обратно-пропорциональный график', 'обратно пропорциональная зависимость', 'обратно-пропорциональная']):
    #какие-то действия
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Я тебя не понял, повтори пожалуйста")
```